# Custom Deserialize of Properties with Json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Json.net api `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` which accepts two parameters first the json string and second the actual object which you want to fill.

The structure of the object that I want to fill is

```
internal class Customer 
{

    public Customer()
    {
        this.CustomerAddress = new Address();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address CustomerAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

My json string is

```
{
    "Name":"Jack",
    "State":"ABC",
    "City":"XX",
    "ZipCode":"098"
}
```

Now the `Name` property gets filled becuase it is present in json string but the `CustomerAddress` is not getting populated. Is there any way by which I can tell the Json.net library that populate `CustomerAddress.City` from the `City` property in the json string ?

Answer (score 1):

Directly - no.

But it should be possible to achieve that, e.g. here is an attempt (assuming you can't change json):

```
class Customer 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address CustomerAddress { get; set; } = new Address(); // initial value

    // private property used to get value from json
    // attribute is needed to use not-matching names (e.g. if Customer already have City)
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Address.City))]
    string _city
    {
        set { CustomerAddress.City = value; }
    }

    // ... same for other properties of Address
}
```

Other possibilities:

- change json format to contain `Address` object;
- custom serialization (e.g. using binder to serialize *fake* type and convert it to needed);
- ... (should be more).